# A doubt on a problem in Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Having tried to solve exercise 4.4-7 to have another proof of Frobenius Theorem, I would ask you a question.

This is what I have understood: 
In Step 2 there is to  prove, for any tangent subbundle $E$ on a manifold $M,$ that if the module $\Gamma(E)$ of its sections is a  Lie subalgebra of $\Gamma(TM)$ then it is locally generated by $k$ independent commuting vector fields.
In Step 1 there is to prove the integrability of $E$ when it is locally generated by $k$ independent commuting vector fields.

Now this is the question: 
Because, in the step 1, the authors assume additionally that $\Gamma(E)$ has to be an abelian Lie subalgebra of $\Gamma(TM)$?
There is some point that I don't understand? or is it a lapsus calami?

Thank you very much for the attention.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question.  I assume you are talking about what in my edition of this book is called exercise 4.4-7.  If so, Step 1 is actually asking you to prove the integrability of E in the abelian case.  Then in Step 2 you show the general involutive case reduces *locally* to the abelian case.

Comment: 1)Yes. It is exactly the problem on an alternative (Hirsch, Weinstein) proof of Frobenius Theorem, and, in its statement, the distribution E is said to be (locally) abelian if (Ab): the submodule \Gamma(E) of its sections is an abelian Lie subalgebra of \Gamma(TM). 2)I just found how to solve the problem when I substitute this latter condition(Ab) with the condition(): E is locally generated by a system of independent and commuting vector fields. And I think that (Ab) is really stronger than (), while (*) is equivalent to involutivity of E. 3)So the request of (Ab) is superfluous, or not?

Comment: It seems to me that "Lie subalgebra generated by k independent commuting vector fields" is not the same thing as "abelian Lie subalgebra".

Comment: Please, about the exercise, should you say me if my way of proof is correct, or not?
if not, where I need to use the stronger condition "\Gamma(E) abelian"?

Comment: Does the book really use the word "abelian"?

Comment:  José Figueroa-O'Farrill, in his comment, reports exactly the statement of the problem 4.4-7 in Abraham, Marsden, Ratiu, MTA.

Comment: It seems to me that they are suggesting the following strategy for proving Frobenius: Step 1: Show that if you have a subbundle $E$ of $T_*M$ such that $\Gamma(E)$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\Gamma(T_*M)$, then $\Gamma(E)$ is locally generated by commuting vector fields. Step 2: Show that if $\Gamma(E)$ is locally generated by commuting vector fields, then for any point $x \in M$, there is a submanifold $S \subset M$ containing $x$ such that $T_*S$ is equal to the bundle $E$ restricted to $S$.

Comment: So you agree with me that the condition $\Gamma(E)$ abelian subalgebra of $\Gamma(TM)$ has to be replaced by the softer condition: $E$ locally generated by a system of independent commuting vector fields.
If so, then the question, for me, could be closed.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how it's even possible for it to be abelian. Does the book give a definition of an "abelian Lie algebra"?

Comment: The book says "Step 1. Prove it [the frobenius theorem] for the abelian case in which all sections of $E$ satisfy $[X,Y]=0$ by choosing a local basis $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ of sections and successively flowing out by the commuting flows of $X_1,\ldots,X_k$." Instead, following Step 2, I arrives only to the conclusion that any involutive distribution is locally generated by a system of independent commuting vector fields.

Comment: Giuseppe, it appears to me that your understanding of this is correct.